# Анимация в XAML WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, анимация

Есть верстка в XAML, в которой есть три TextBlock и один ComboBox. Нужно, чтобы при переходе на эту страницу, Opacity у всех элементов, кроме первого TextBox (Title) было 0. А сам Title делал бы отступ 50 вверх от того, места где он сейчас находится и перемещался на своё место (через 3 секунды - отступ вверх=0, анимация перехода). После того, как Title занял своё место (завершил анимацию), у всех элементов Opacity=1.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.35*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Text="Заголовок страницы" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="35" Padding="0 10 0 25" FontFamily="Calibri Bold" Name="Title"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Подзаголовок" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="25" Padding="0 50 0 0" FontFamily="Calibri" Name="SubTitle"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="25">
                <TextBlock Text="Варианты: " FontSize="18" Name="Options"/>
            <ComboBox SelectedIndex="1" Padding="2" FontSize="18" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" Name="dm">
                <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>4</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>5</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего сложного нет. Создаем две анимации: одну для заголовка, другую - для Grid содержащий элементы, которые через 3 секунды после загрузки страницы нужно отобразить.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="titleAnimation" AutoReverse="True">
    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
        <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.5" Value="50"/>
    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Key="contentAnimation">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" BeginTime="00:00:03"/>
</Storyboard>
```

дальее запускаем их по событию `Window.Loaded`:

```
<TextBlock Text="Заголовок страницы" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="35" Padding="0 10 0 25" FontFamily="Calibri Bold" Name="Title"  >
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource titleAnimation}"/>         
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>


<Grid Grid.Row="1" Opacity="0">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource contentAnimation}"/>     
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    ...
</Grid>
```

готово!

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не могли бы Вы пояснить, за счёт чего двигается надпись?

Comment: @A.Hall засчет анимирования свойства Margin

Comment: Не подскажите, как именно их нужно внедрить в код. При попытке добавить Storyboard, у меня показывает ошибку: Значение типа Storyboard не может быть добавлено к коллекции или словарю типа UIElementCollection

Comment: Сами анимации вы расположили в ресурсах? Подключение описано в ответе.

Comment: Как расположить анимации в ресурсах?